# simple listview (not activity) example?

Tags: android, listview, layout

I've been doing this for a few months now and I've found it almost impossible to find an example where the ListView is a ListView not a ListActivity. In my program all I'm wanting to do is have half the screen a ListView and the other half something else so the ListView can be moved around in the layout. Does anyone know any such examples?

Comment: See this link: may be it helps you. [Click here...](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-example)

Comment: also see this link :  http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2009/12/android-selected-state-listview-example/

Comment: and also this link: http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/

Comment: The bellow link provides the tutorial for ListView without using the ListActivity..
http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php

Answer (score 0):

I have created implementation of ListView, not ListActivity.

**list_produk.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvListProduk"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.98"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_produk_row" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnListProdukBack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/back_" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_produk_row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProdukName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ListProduk.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_produk);

    String[] from = new String[] {"prd_name"};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tvProdukName};

    List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("prd_name", "BlackBerry");
    fillMaps.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("prd_name", "Android");
    fillMaps.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("prd_name", "iPhone");
    fillMaps.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.list_produk_row, from, to);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListProduk);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

list_produk_row.xml, that contains a TextView, is the layout for list item of ListView.